# php - Regular Expression to match someting that starts with

Tags: php, regex

I am terribly sorry but the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => msie6.0
        [1] => 7
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => safari5.0.3
        [1] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => chrome18.0.1025.308
        [1] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => firefox20.0
        [1] => 4
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => msie7.0
        [1] => 915
    )
```

and so on...
When i try to replace for example `msie6.0`and `msie7.0` with `InternetExplorer` and add it occurence :

```
preg_match("/#^msie(.*)$#i/is", $results, $matches);
$test = $matches[0] ;
print_array($test);
$results["#^startText(.*)$#i"] = $results['InternetExplorer'];
print_array($results);
unset($results["/#^msie(.*)$#i/is]);
```

it not match the perfect as i want. any solution for that ?
in order to have :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => InternetExplorer
        [1] => 922
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => safari5.0.3
        [1] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => chrome18.0.1025.308
        [1] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => firefox20.0
        [1] => 4
    )
```

Comment: You want to replace a part by "InternetExplorer" or whole key ?

Comment: I want to replace every key that start with `msie` and add it value to have in the end `InternetExplorer` with the sum of all its values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your clarification in comment. I think you don't need regex, [*strpos*](https://www.php.net/strpos) is enough too that job.

```
$rows["InternetExplorer"] = 0;
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
  if(strpos($key,"msie") !== false){
     $rows["InternetExplorer"] += $value;
     unset($rows[$key]);
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/e2SB1wNm)**.

Comment: Sorry! I've edited my post! I want it to look like the result.

Comment: Have you tried my code ? Check the demo link ? It will give you the same result as you expect.